# How do you write a JPA join expression when joining on non-primary key columns?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

I'm using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  How do I write a JPA join that joins the two tables on a non-primary key column?  I have two entities, Link and Training, both with an orderId field, but I don't know how to write a Join expression.  Normally, I could write

```
Root<Link>root=criteriaQuery.from(Link.class);
...
Join<Link, Training> link = root.join("trainingId");
```

However, this assumes the tables are linked by a primary key, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would with JPQL, you need multiple FROM entities

```
Root<Link> rootLink = criteriaQuery.from(Link.class);
Root<Training> rootTraining = criteriaQuery.from(Training.class);
...
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootLink.get(link_.linkAttribute), trainingLink.get(training_.trainingAttribute)));
```